# HTTP-POST XHR not working in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cross-browser, xmlhttprequest

I am working on a Web App in which I need to call to the server cgi which will in turn use this data for further use.
It working fine in IE6+ and FF but not in chrome 15.(not yet checked with IE6)
Here is my code :

```
 var destinationURL = "/cgi-bin/conf.cgi";
 var xmlHttpReq = getXMLHttpRequest();
    if(xmlHttpReq == null){
        return false;
    } 
    if (xmlHttpReq.readyState == 0){
        xmlHttpReq.open('POST', destinationURL, true);
        xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {            
            if (xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {              
                alert(xmlHttpReq.responseText);                
            }
        }
        xmlHttpReq.send();                
    }
```

And getXMLHttpRequest() function is :

```
function getXMLHttpRequest() {
    var xmlHttpReq;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlHttpReq = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        try {
            xmlHttpReq = new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(ex) {
            alert('Exception in initializing the XMLHttpRequest object '+ex.toString());
            return null;
        }
    }
    return xmlHttpReq;
}
```

Any solutions ?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: I have changed it from POST to GET and it worked...!!!

But What if I want to strictly use POST ???

Answer (score 0):

I will use the following code in getXMLHttpRequest() method:

```
var xmlhttp;
if(navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
} else {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
```

Try that and let us know

Comment: I have tried your code but still not getting expected result.