# PHP POST variable not defined when using Chrome + XHR

Tags: php, javascript, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

This question is nearly identical to the year-old unanswered question:

[HTTP-POST XHR not working in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033263/http-post-xhr-not-working-in-chrome).

I was hoping to find a solution and can offer more details than the original question.

**Background**

I have a sever-side php script that is supposed to take POST data from a form or XHR request. When I test the site using a form for submission, it works in Chrome and IE9. However, when I generate the request using XHR, the php POST variable is undefined when using Chrome on the client side. This behavior is inconsistent: about 1 in 20 tries, the php does accept the data.

I have checked the `php://input` stream and see that the post data is being sent to server in all cases; and note that a small few of the HTTP headers (`$_SERVER`) are different between test cases.

**Code**

Server side:

```
<?php
   echo file_get_contents("php://input") . "\n";
   print_r($_SERVER);
   print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Client side form version (Chrome and IE9 both work)

```
<form action="scriptName.php" method="post">
      Field: <input type="text" name="myField"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Client side XHR version (IE9 always works, Chrome works about 5% of time)

```
<script>
function postToURL(url,data)
{
  // Typical XHLHttpRequest declarations are removed for brevity
  //  - checks browser type and declares xmlhttp accordingly
  //  - defines a onreadystatechange handle

    xmlhttp.open("POST",url,false);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(data);
}
</script>
...
<form>
<button type="button" onClick="postToURL('scriptname.php','myField=test');">
Test
</button>
</form>
```

**Output**

In all cases the request body data (`php://input`) returns the same value.
The headers are mostly the same, but Chrome adds an `[HTTP_PRAGMA] => no-cache` in XHR mode

The `$_POST` variable is defined  as `[myField] => test` except in the Chrome + XHR case.

**Questions**

Where is the problem likely occurring? Is there something wrong with the HTTP headers possibly, or should I be looking server-side. Any ideas?

Comment: When is `postToURL()` called?

Comment: It is called from a button `onClick` event.

Comment: Can you show us that please?

Comment: the `[HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH]` header is the same all cases (12 when `myField=test`). I will try to manually define it and see if that changes the behavior.

Comment: @Nile: updated the code as requested

Comment: Setting the `Content-Length` does not work in IE and is disallowed in Chrome: "Refused to set unsafe header "Content-Length"

Comment: Works as expected for me (PHP 5.4.6, Chrome 24.0 beta). Sends the POST every time. Have you tested in a different environment?

Comment: @ithcy: well it's good to know it's not a universal Chrome bug. I have limited environments to test on. I am using Chrome 23.0, PHP 5.4.10 w/ built-in development web-server. I can push up to the 24.0 beta and see what happens; I am starting to feel the issue is server-side though.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not so sure. Can you use `apache_request_headers()` to see if the content type of the post is actually being set correctly when $_POST is not being populated?

Comment: @ithcy: Not running apache, just using standalone php.exe with -S option. The "server" has very limited RAM to allocate for the web hosting (less than 4MB). I will have to look at this more closely: using jQuery, the POSTs are working.

Comment: hmm... well you could always `parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $_POST);` if you don't want jQuery... but if you can use it, why not :)

Comment: Use Chrome's web inspector to examine the request and response headers - it should tell you exactly what Chrome is sending to / receiving from the server.

Comment: @nicholas @broofa is right... Since the string is always coming through on `php://input`, but not on `$_POST`, this *should* indicate that the Content-Type header is not being set correctly by Chrome. PHP will not automatically populate $_POST when Content-Type is NOT `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. That's why i was asking if you could inspect that header on the server side.

Comment: Have you tried setting the charset? xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8")

Comment: When you monitor the network tab within chrome when you click the button and the request is sent what is being set ?

Comment: Are you sure you're tracking the XHR request and not the 'regular' form submit? Your postToURL() doesn't return false, so might submit the regular form as well?

Answer (score 1):

**Place this code in the first line of your page**

```
<?php ob_start(); error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~8192); ?>
<!-- Ignore Errors , Header Sent Report -->
```

**and this code in the last line of your page**

```
<!-- Ignore Header Sent Error -->
<?php ob_flush(); ?>
<!-- Ignore Header Sent Error -->
```

i hope that helps you